# Why does $a_n=\sqrt{n} + \sin(n)$ diverge?

Tags: divergent-series

I know the sequence does not converge to a point, so it must diverge. It is bounded on the bottom by 0 and there is no upper bound. So does it diverge because it is not bounded or because it oscillates?
Thanks.

Comment: because $\sqrt{n}$ diverges and $sin(n)$ which is between $-1$ and $1$ is negligible as the first term becomes large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence
$$
a_n = \sqrt{n} + \sin(n)
$$
diverges because it grows without bound. For any given $M$ you can find an $n$ such that $a_n > M$. That's it.

---

Now, it is bounded below, but not above. If you have a sequence that is bounded below and above, and if it is monotonic (i.e. strictly increasing or decreasing from a point) then it will be convergent. But your example is not bounded above.

Comment: Thank you - great explanation!

Comment: The sequence $a_n$ is bounded below though, so this argument isn't sufficient to show that it doesn't converge since it isn't monotonic.

Comment: @user1892304: **If** it is monotonic and **if** it is bounded **then** it converges. You can use this fact to prove that it doesn't converge. It is true, however, that a convergent sequence is bounded, so if it is not bounded then it is not convergent.

Comment: @Thomas Yes you're right, sorry. I was confusing the limit of a sequence and that of a function.

Answer (score 0):

For all $n \geq 1$ we have
$\sqrt{n} + \sin n \geq \sqrt{n} - 1$;
given any $M > 0$,
we have $\sqrt{n} - 1 > M$ if $n > (M+1)^{2}$;
but then $n > (M+1)^{2}$ only if $\sqrt{n} + \sin n > M$.
This shows that the desired sequence diverges to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Thomas' answer we can see that $\sin(n) \in [-1,1]$ which is bounded both above and below and that $\sqrt{n}$ is unbounded. Then we can use the fact that sum of unbounded and bounded is unbounded.